# How do I create a preferences window in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I would like to create a preferences window like in the standard Mac OS X apps (Safari etc.).  I have found resources like [DBPrefsWindowController](http://www.mere-mortal-software.com/blog/details.php?d=2007-03-11) from back in 2008 that matches the Apple HIG.

Just wondering if there is a new way to accomplish this?  I can't locate any standard windows in Interface Builder so I assume Apple doesn't provide those, nor can I locate a official Apple sample code for providing this standard UI.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It seems `DBPrefsWindowController` is no longer available.

For now, I would recommend the up to date `RHPreferences` framework.

Available on [GitHub](https://github.com/heardrwt/RHPreferences). BSD Licensed.

It’s a simple and easy Preferences window controller with multiple tabs for your next Mac application.

It also provides:

- Auto resizing between different sized tab views (With animation)
- Custom `NSToolbarItem` support
- Persistence of the last used tab
- Support for placeholder `NSToolbarItems` (eg `NSToolbarFlexibleSpaceItemIdentifier` & `NSToolbarShowFontsItemIdentifier`)