# How to make preferences menu item in the menu to display user preferences in os-x application?

Tags: macos

I am trying with hours to activate preferences option in the menu. I am trying to build trivial  app for Mac (os x).

I already use NSUserDefaults, to let the user to check / uncheck some options. However, I want to provide him an option to change again those settings. Preferences menu item  seems great place for that.

What I would like to do is when user click on the preferences menu, preference panel to be opened, where I can add few check boxes. Anyone know how can I do that (invoke a panel that I can modify)?

I am trying to control drag from the preferences item to my first responder, but I can't find an option that does what I need. Anyone can give me some clue?

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards, John

Comment: Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: Code is written in Objective-C

Comment: This question has already been [asked and answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757725/how-do-i-create-a-preferences-window-in-objective-c).

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look on it, but I remain stunned to find out that there is no solution provided by the cocoa itself.

Comment: there are solution provided by cocoa: NSWindow, NSCheckBox etc...